# Issues in the admin panel on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

First of all i'm a french developer so i'm sorry for my english ;-)

I have many issues on the admin panel of my Drupal 7 Website. I made a full copy of my production website to have it on a preproduction environnement (exactly the same server configuration).

It's tough to explain my problem even in french so i made a few screenshot to illustrate. On every pictures yo have the preproduction site on the left and the production site on  the right.

Screenshot 1 : Where is my wysiwyg ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYR1w.png

Screenshot 2 : The list (ex : style settings) are inactive https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L8Lo.png

Screenshot 3 : No arrows to re-order my blocks https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddzSU.png

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Gaëtan

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is related to JS issue. Did you check the console?